# Hide a Drupal block on mobile devices

Tags: drupal, drupal-8, drupal-blocks, drupal-9

I'm making a new Drupal site which is based on a non-bootstrap theme and makes heavy use of blocks to place content.
Some blocks display content that is better to hide on smaller screens to have a nicer look and feel. I want to hide them, but I don't know how to do it.
I'm using Drupal 9. I understand that there are some modules that can help in this situation, but those I know don't work with D9.

Comment: Back-end is not aware of screen (window) dimensions and similar. You have to hide block on front-end side.  https://www.webdesignersacademy.com/show-and-hide-different-content-on-mobile-devices-desktops/

Answer (score 2):

Why use modules when CSS will do, something like

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .blockname {
    display: none;
 }
}
```